# ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual mysql stored procedure error

Tags: mysql

I am just trying mysql stored procedure but I am getting the following error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near ';
>
> DECLARE cur CURSOR for
> select birth_date from employees;
>
> ' at line 3

Code:

```
delimiter //
create procedure getminmaxbirthdate(OUT minage date,OUT maxage date)
    begin
        DECLARE minsofar,maxsofar,curage,done;

        DECLARE cur CURSOR for
            select birth_date from employees;

        set minsofar = 2040-12-12;
        set maxsofar = 0;
        set done = 0;

        DECLARE continue handler for not found
            set done = 1;

        open cur;
            while done = 0 do
                fetch birthdate into curage;
                if curage > maxsofar then
                    set maxsofar = curage;
                end if;
                if curage < minsofar then
                    set minsofar = curage;
                end if;
            end while;    
        close cur;

        set minage = minsofar;
        set maxage = maxsofar;
    end //
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Why use a stored procedure for this at all? You can get the information you want with a straight SQL query.

Comment: @GMB I am just learning

Answer (score 1):

You have some bugs in your code

- DECLARE without a tyoe is nocht valid
- SET are only possible after DECLARE
- and your  CORSOR is cur not birthdate

you **must check** the datatypes for **minsofar,maxsofar,curage,done**

stored procedure:

```
   delimiter //
 create procedure getminmaxbirthdate(OUT minage date,OUT maxage date)
    begin
        DECLARE minsofar,maxsofar,curage,done VARCHAR(10);

        DECLARE cur CURSOR for
            select birth_date from employees;
            
        DECLARE continue handler for not found
            set done = 1;

        set minsofar = 2040-12-12;
        set maxsofar = 0;
        set done = 0;


        open cur;
            while done = 0 do
                fetch cur into curage;
                if curage > maxsofar then
                    set maxsofar = curage;
                end if;
                if curage < minsofar then
                    set minsofar = curage;
                end if;
            end while;    
        close cur;

        set minage = minsofar;
        set maxage = maxsofar;
    end //
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you are not using a simple query?

```
select min(birth_date), max(birth_date)
from employee;
```

This *could* be incorporated into a stored procedure, but that seems superfluous.  Using a cursor is just a really, really, really bad practice -- even if you are learning SQL.  Cursors should be avoided, except in the situations where they are necessary -- such as calling a stored procedure or invoking dynamic SQL for each row.

Your code also seems to be mixing up "ages" and "dates".  It is a bit unclear what you really want to accomplish.

Comment: I just want to output minimum age and maximum age

Comment: @SugumarVenkatesan . . . Just calculate the age from the minimum and maximum birthdates.